# PNG to DDS with Imagick missing Set Arguments

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick, mipmaps

I would like to use the PHP Code like this example

```
<?
$img = new Imagick('test.png'); //Load the uploaded image
$img->setformat('dds'); //Set the format to dds
$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_DXT5); //Set compression method
$img->writeimage('test.dds'); //Write/save the dds texture
?>
```

but i cant find the missing set Arguments for Cluster-fit true|false and Mipmaps = X
so i am stuck to use php exec which forces me to save the png first so exec() can reach it to convert it into dds.

```
exec("convert -format dds -define dds:compression=dxt5 -define dds:mipmaps=6 -define dds:cluster-fit=true ".$ziptempDir.$fileName." ".$ziptempDir.$fileNameDDS."");
```

i can`t find the Arguments on php.net , so are they not aivailible for php imagick and if so, does anybody know how to get/translate them to use it like in the first example ?

Thanks

Comment: Try something like `$imagick->setOption("dds:mipmaps", 6);`

Comment: Wow, it works ... i tried it before but i bet i had an typo there. thank you very much !

Comment: Cool! As you have working, tested code, you can write it up for others to see and grab the points by accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working Code with the setOptions for mipmaps x and cluster-fit true|false which is not descriped on php.net

```
    $imgSkinFull->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_DXT5);
    $imgSkinFull->setOption("dds:mipmaps", 6);
    $imgSkinFull->setOption("dds:cluster-fit", true);
    $imgSkinFull->setformat('dds');
    $imgSkinFull->writeimage($ziptempDir.$fileNameDDS);
    $imgSkinFull->destroy();
```

Comment: Cool, thank you for sharing back with the SO community.